# Standard Least-Squares Minimisation

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Minimise the residual error gives us the standard least-squares problem:
\begin{equation}
\text{arg min}_x||Ax-b||^2
\end{equation}

First we rewrite the above as follows:
\begin{equation}
F(x)=(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)\\
F(x)= (x^TA^T-b^T)(Ax-b)\\
F(x)= x^TA^TA x- x^TA^Tb-b^TAx+b^Tb\\
F(x) = x^TA^TA x- 2x^TA^Tb+b^Tb
\end{equation}

**Question 1**: Why $x^TA^Tb=b^TAx$ ?

To derive the solution $x$, (with help) I calculated the gradient of the above:
\begin{equation}
\nabla F(x)= 2x^TA^TA-2A^Tb
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\nabla F(x)=0 \Rightarrow x^TA^TA=A^Tb
\end{equation}
**Question 2:** How can I prove that $x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, realize $b^TAx=(x^TA^Tb)^T$, and $b^TAx$ is just a number, i.e. $1\times 1$ matrix. Thus, it is equal to its transpose.

For your second question, just transpose everything again, then you'll have $$A^TAx = (x^TA^TA)^T=(A^Tb)^T=b^TA\implies x=(A^TA)^{-1}b^TA$$